# optgroup in updatepanel keeps the highlight in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, internet-explorer-11, optgroup

When I use the optgroup in a select and the select is inside a updatepanel I have a strange issue since IE 11 is installed.

The selected value keeps being highlighted althought the cursor is in another field.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlContent" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <select>
        <optgroup label="Alkaline Metals">
          <option>Lithium (Li)</option>
          <option>Sodium (Na)</option>
          <option>Potassium (K)</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Halogens">
          <option>Fluorine (F)</option>
          <option>Chlorine (Cl)</option>
          <option>Bromine (Br)</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>  
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks for any response that can help me!

Comment: Hi - did you ever get to the bottom of this?
I've got the same issue - on a standard HTA application - a select drop down that contains optgroups retains the option highlighting when the item looses focus!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and discovered it was due to the fact that I was emitting a  tag in the HTML header which was instructing IE to render in IE7 compatibility mode.

The header was:

```
<META content="IE=7.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

Removing this fixed the highlighting problem.